# "Classic symptoms" or "classical symptoms"?

Tags: word-choice, ic-ical

According to Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, both 'classic' and 'classical' mean very typical in a sense. However, in Longman Dictionary of contemporary English and Oxford Collocations Dictionary only 'classic' collocates with 'symptoms'. So, are these two sentences perfectly correct?
***1- She displayed the classic symptoms of depression.***
***2- She displayed the classical symptoms of depression.***
If not, why? Is it a matter of collocations? Is it a matter of common usage?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You just have to know these on a case-by-case basis. We speak of "classical music" (symphonies and operas and the like) but "classic rock" (electric guitars, Top 40, etc.).

Comment: You could use "classical symptoms of depression" in the sense of  "relating to the first significant period of an area of study" (see TimLymington's link) - i.e., the symptoms that an 18th- or 19th-century doctor would have recognized as "depression" in contrast to the way that a 21st-century psychology textbook describes the condition.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use *classic* to mean 'typical' with symptoms [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=classic%20symptoms%20of%20depression%2Cclassical%20symptoms%20of%20depression&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclassic%20symptoms%20of%20depression%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclassical%20symptoms%20of%20depression%3B%2Cc0) shows a much less common   use of *classical  symptoms of depression vs classic symptoms of depression* . See below the definitions:

***Classical:***

> - has a few narrow definitions, including
>
>   - (1) of or relating to the ancient Greeks or Romans,
>   - (2) of or relating to a peak stage of a civilization, and
>   - (3) of or relating to European orchestral music of the late 18th and early 19th centuries.
> - These aren’t the only definitions of classical. *What’s important is that the term usually relates to fairly well-defined historical periods of culture and science.*

***Classic:***

> - is broader. Its main adjectival definitions are
>
>   - (1) of lasting significance or worth
>   - (2) typical, and
>   - (3) adhering to established standards of elegance or restraint.
> - As a noun, it means an enduring work, and as a plural, with the (and usually capitalized—the Classics), it refers to the literature of ancient Greece and Rome.

[The Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/classic-classical/)

Both sources below don't define   "classical" with  the connotation  of 'typical of its kind'.

[Classic vs classical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269978/classic-or-classical) (dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar)

[Classical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/classical) (ODO)